# App engine flex java: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: javax/tools/DiagnosticListener : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: app-engine-flexible

when I tried to deploy app in app engine flex from iCloud shell, I am getting below error

failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.1:compile: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: 
javax/tools/DiagnosticListener : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_131"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-8u131-b11-1~bpo8+1-b11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)

but javac version is still pointing to 1.7.0_131... How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

do same alternative update command will solve the issue